# How to avoid python script code mess and optimization?

Tags: python, optimization

I have created a Python script that builds a calendar (`.xlsx` file) with people assigned to rewrite and overhaul the lessons of my college professors.

The code, however, is rather "wordy" and, almost certainly, not optimized. How can I proceed? Do you have any advice (including any texts that I could read to increase my knowledge)?

Here's my script:

```
import xlsxwriter
#use xlsxwriter functions to initializate\create .xlsx file 
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
#Defining start informations
day = 24 #first day of the calendar
nday = 1 #nday stands for the week day (1=monday, ..., 7=sunday)
month = 10 #month number
trentuno = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12] #array that defines month that have 31 days
settimana = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5] #array that defines working days
i=0
f=open('test.txt') #inside this file we have the names (one per line) of people that is going to be in the calendar
lines=f.readlines()
array = [] #void array that is going to be "the excel table"
array.append(["data", "ora", "sbobinatore", "controllore"])
festa = ["1/11", "8/12", "26/12", "27/12", "28/12", "29/12", "30/12", "2/1", "3/1", "4/1", "5/1", "6/1"] #holidays
due = ["9/1", "10/1", "11/1", "12/1", "13/1", "16/1", "17/1", "18/1", "19/1", "20/1"] #days with only 2h lessons
while i < len(lines):
    data = "%d/%d" % (day,month)    
    if nday in settimana and not data in festa:
        ora = "[9:00-11:00]"
        sbobinatore1 = lines[i] # "sbobinatore" is the person who writes the lesson
        controllore1 = lines[i+1] # "controllore" is the person who check the rewrited lesson
        array.append([data, ora, sbobinatore1, controllore1])
        i = i+2
        ora2 = "[11:00-13:00]"
        sbobinatore2 = lines[i]
        controllore2 = lines[i+1]
        array.append([data, ora, sbobinatore2, controllore2])
        i = i+2
        if month in trentuno:
            if day == 31:
                day = 1
                nday = nday+1
                month = month+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
        elif month == 2:
            if day == 28:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
        else:
            if day == 30:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
#if the day is not a working day
    else:                               
        if month in trentuno:
            if day == 31:
                day = 1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
                month = month+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
        elif month == 2:
            if day == 28:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
        else:
            if day == 30:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
#repeating the while with role invertion
i=0
while i < len(lines):
    data = "%d/%d" % (day,month)    
    if nday in settimana and not data in festa:
        ora = "[9:00-11:00]"
        sbobinatore1 = lines[i+1]
        controllore1 = lines[i]
        array.append([data, ora, sbobinatore1, controllore1])
        i = i+2
        ora2 = "[11:00-13:00]"
        sbobinatore2 = lines[i+1]
        controllore2 = lines[i]
        array.append([data, ora, sbobinatore2, controllore2])
        i = i+2
        if month in trentuno:
            if day == 31:
                day = 1
                nday = nday+1
                month = month+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
        elif month == 2:
            if day == 28:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
        else:
            if day == 30:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                nday = nday+1
#if the day is not a working day or holiday
    else:                               
        if month in trentuno:
            if day == 31:
                day = 1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
                month = month+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
        elif month == 2:
            if day == 28:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
        else:
            if day == 30:
                day = 1
                month = month+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
            else:
                day = day+1
                if nday == 7:
                    nday = 1
                else:
                    nday = nday+1
#sight check
print(array)
#defining starting point for the creation of the table inside the xlsx worksheet
row = 0
col = 0
#actual creation of the table
for a, b, c, d in (array):
    worksheet.write(row, col, a)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, b)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, c)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, d)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: You probably want to put some of your logic in function(s).

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. Otherwise, read [ask] and be clearer about the problem.